# Calculate the triangular matrix of distances between NumPy array of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an NumPy array of coordinates.  For example purposes, I will use this

```
In [1]: np.random.seed(123)
In [2]: coor = np.random.randint(10, size=12).reshape(-1,3)
In [3]: coor
Out[3]: array([[2, 2, 6],
               [1, 3, 9],
               [6, 1, 0],
               [1, 9, 0]])
```

I want the triangular matrix of distances between all coordinates.  A  simple approach would be to code a double loop over all coordinates

```
In [4]: n_coor = len(coor)
In [5]: dist = np.zeros((n_coor, n_coor))
In [6]: for j in xrange(n_coor):
            for k in xrange(j+1, n_coor):
                dist[j, k] = np.sqrt(np.sum((coor[j] - coor[k]) ** 2))
```

with the result being an upper triangular matrix of the distances

```
In [7]: dist
Out[7]: array([[  0.        ,   3.31662479,   7.28010989,   9.2736185 ],
               [  0.        ,   0.        ,  10.48808848,  10.81665383],
               [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   9.43398113],
               [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]])
```

Leveraging NumPy, I can avoid looping using

```
In [8]: dist = np.sqrt(((coor[:, None, :] - coor) ** 2).sum(-1))
```

but the result is the entire matrix

```
In [9]: dist
Out[9]: array([[  0.        ,   3.31662479,   7.28010989,   9.2736185 ],
               [  3.31662479,   0.        ,  10.48808848,  10.81665383],
               [  7.28010989,  10.48808848,   0.        ,   9.43398113],
               [  9.2736185 ,  10.81665383,   9.43398113,   0.        ]])
```

This one line version takes roughly half the time when I use 2048 coordinates (4 s instead of 10 s) but this is doing twice as many calculations as it needs in order to get the symmetric matrix. Is there a way to adjust the one line command to only get the triangular matrix (and the additional 2x speedup, i.e. 2 s)?

Comment: If all that is needed is the distances, not in a matrix, [SciPy's `pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) introduced by @Divaker returns exactly this (there is no need to use `trip_indices` or boolean-indexing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [SciPy's `pdist` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to get those distances. So, we just need to initialize the output array and then set the upper triangular values with those distances

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

n_coor = len(coor)
dist = np.zeros((n_coor, n_coor))
row,col = np.triu_indices(n_coor,1)
dist[row,col] = pdist(coor)
```

Alternatively, we can use boolean-indexing to assign values, replacing the last two lines

```
dist[np.arange(n_coor)[:,None] < np.arange(n_coor)] = pdist(coor)
```

---

**Runtime test**

Functions:

```
def subscripted_indexing(coor):
    n_coor = len(coor)
    dist = np.zeros((n_coor, n_coor))
    row,col = np.triu_indices(n_coor,1)
    dist[row,col] = pdist(coor)
    return dist

def boolean_indexing(coor):
    n_coor = len(coor)
    dist = np.zeros((n_coor, n_coor))
    r = np.arange(n_coor)
    dist[r[:,None] < r] = pdist(coor)
    return dist
```

Timings:

```
In [110]: # Setup input array
     ...: coor = np.random.randint(0,10, (2048,3))

In [111]: %timeit subscripted_indexing(coor)
10 loops, best of 3: 91.4 ms per loop

In [112]: %timeit boolean_indexing(coor)
10 loops, best of 3: 47.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice! Running for 2048 coordinates without `boolean-indexing` took 588 ms and with `boolean-indexing` took 135 ms.

Comment: @stvn66 Yup, getting similar results here! Added into the post.

Comment: How many coordinates are you testing with?  I found using just a few (e.g., the four in my example) led to artificial differences.

Comment: @stvn66 Oops! Forgot to add that before, just done that.

Comment: I also just tested this using Fortran wrapped using [f2py from NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/) and it turned out to be slower than the SciPy versions.  For comparison, here are the timings I get on my setup (repeated several times to get consistency): simple-Python, 10.3 s; NumPy, 4 s; SciPy v1, 107 ms; SciPy v2, 84 ms; f2py, 178 ms.

Comment: @stvn66 Kool! Thanks for reporting back with those timings.